# Can a same method exist in a class twice, through Inheritance and interfaces?

Tags: java, interface

Here is the scenario:-

```
class Canine{
  public void roam(){
    System.out.println("Canine-Roam");
  }
}

public interface Pet{    
  public abstract void roam();
}


class Dog extends Canine implements Pet{

  public void roam(){
    System.out.println("Dog Roam");
  }
  public static void main(String [] args){
    Dog adog = new Dog();
    adog.roam();
  }
}
```

I am aware that JVM must not have any confusion in choosing which method to run, that means, which method gets over-ridden. But I am confused anyway. Why does this program compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - the same method cannot exist in a class twice.

An interface simply declares a *requirement* for a class to implement a particular method.  It does not actually create that method.

So a class that acquires a method implemention through inheritance has that method defined.  This (single) implementation satisfies the interface's requirements.

In your case:

1. `Dog` extends `Canine`, so it means that the `roam()` method from `Canine` is available, and would be exposed as a method on Dog objects if not overridden.
2. But then `Dog` then *overrides* the superclass' method with its own definition of `roam()`.  This is allowed, and there is still just one unambiguous method called `roam()` on `Dog` - the new override.
3. `Dog` implements `Pet`, which means it is required to have a `roam()` method.  It does - so it's a valid implementation of this interface.

Comment: thanks, is it safe to assume that the method roam over-rides the method from interface

Comment: @Ankit - There is no "method **from** the interface".  It's essential you understand that.  An interface just describes a sort of contract that classes must conform to, if they want to be able to say "yes, I implement `Pet`".  `Dog` has a method called `roam()` on it - therefore, it can be declared as `... implements Pet`.  There is no `Pet.roam()` method to override.

Comment: Or to put it another way - let's say that it *didn't* "override the method from the interface".  What do you expect this method from the interface to do?

Comment: thanks sir; i have a sub-question:- "implementing a method from an interface, isn't overriding ?"

Answer (score 2):

Your case is totally fine and it will run fine and outputs `Dog Roam`. That means the function in `Dog` class runs.

You did not get any compile time errors because the method in Dog is implementing the abstract method **declared** in interface and coincidentally the method signature of this method matches with the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you confuse two things:

- Implementation: **what is done?** see: `Canine.roam()` and `Dog.roam()`
- Interface: **how do you invoke it?** see: `Pet.roam()`

It's clear that you have two "implementations" of `roam()` in two classes:

- `Canine.roam()`
- `Dog.roam()`

There are **never** two same methods in same class.

And because `Dog` extends `Canine`, the method `Canine.roam()` got overriden. Your `main()` function **uses** `Dog.roam()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You had created object for Dog type and assigned it to Dog reference type.
Overridding, has nothing to do here. Though you extended Dog class from canine, both are 2 different types.
At compile time, the compiler checks whether the method definition is present in Reference type. Thats it. And it has to be present there.
At run time, JVM checks for the method in reference type first, then it finds is there any over ridden version for the same method present in "Reference type's " subclass.
If present, it will be executed. Or else, Reference type's method will be executed.

i.e.

```
Canine c=new Dog();
```

will execute Dog's method.