# Is it bad practice to implement an interface twice?

Tags: architecture, uml, dry, class-design, solid-principles

I'm left clueless in this architectural puzzle and I would love to hear some critisim or suggestions about it.

**Situation:**

An *Entity* and *Relation* both have shared (INode) and unique methods (IEntity or IRelation)

**A Class** needs to know about both shared and unique methods using either the interface IEntity or IRelation.

**Question:**

Are the architectures below good or bad practice while trying to program using the S.O.L.I.D & DRY principle?

*additional information: the main reason for this question is because in the first diagram (currently implemented) both Entity and Relation implement the INode interface twice.*

**Situation 1:**

[image: situation 1]

**Situation 2:**

[image: situation 2]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084980/can-a-same-method-exist-in-a-class-twice-through-inheritance-and-interfaces

Answer (score 5):

Your diagrams illustrate very well the subtle difference between [separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/) (conceptual) and [interface segregation](https://devonblog.com/software-development/solid-violations-in-the-wild-the-interface-segregation-principle/) (class design).

In your case there are not two, but **four** options:

1. Your first diagram says that `IEntity` and `IRelation` are specialisations of `INode`.  An `IEntity` is ALWAYS a `INode`.  You may write code that processes entities and relations as nodes but there is a reduced reusability: `IEntity` is coupled to `INode`, even if it's two different unrelated concepts.
2. Your second diagram says that `IEntity` and `IRelation` are different unrelated things when looking at them through their interface.  Both are now decoupled and usable independently, but you fail to recognize that they have something in common and are thus obliged to deal with them separately.
3. Another variant would be the solution 1, but without inheritance between interfaces. In this approach you have independent interfaces: `IEntity` would implement both a general and a specific interface.  Advantage:  you have interface segregation as in 2, but with a better separation of concerns.  The inconvenience is that `IEntity` may not be self-standing anymore.
4. Yet another variant (my favourite), would be to split `INode` in two independent interfaces: a general `INamedObject` and a specific graph interface  `INode`.  `IEntity` and `IRelation` would then inherit from `INamedObject` but not from `INode`.  The advantage is that you have a true separation of concerns:  things are not separated artificially for technical reasons, but according to the concept they represent.

In the end, even if personally I'd advise for option 4, you have to find the right balance for your own design.  Because only you can know how you intend to use your interfaces and classes and the concepts you really want to represent.

[image]